# How to get the URL/NSURL of a single Page in PDF?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit, quicklook

I am using Swift and Xcode to make an iOS app that views PDFs. I can get my current PDF's URL and NSURL the following way:

```
let documentURL = self.pdfDocument?.documentURL?.path
let documentNSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentURL!)
```

I would like to do the same for a certain page of a PDF - for instance, the 500th page out of a 1000 page PDF. I just want that one page as a NSURL.
Given my current viewed page (and I can get the page number too):

```
let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage
```

How can I get/create a NSURL to just this one page?

Does it help that PDFPage is a subclass of NSObject?

This is so I can load just one page into a QuickLookPreviewContainer, where I can use iOS's Markup Feature (to annotate) on just that page. QLPreviewContainer only accepts NSURLs.

Currently, I can load QLPreviewContainer with the entire PDF, but scrolling 500 pages takes a long time...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var pdfView = PDFView()

pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("coritario.pdf"))

let i = 5
var page = self.pdfView.document?.page(at: i)

pdfView.go(to: (page!))
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.